# notify the data changed on server in android app with Notification

Tags: android, service, notifications, broadcastreceiver

I am developing an app which gets the data from MySql server using the PHP script in JSON format and displays in the Activity.

I want that whenever the new data is inserted inside the MySql Server Database my app should show the notification also when the app is closed i.e. not in pause state.

How would I achieve this in my app.
Thanks for your time.

Comment: Please paste your readings,source and whatever you have tried before asking. [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to use in this case Push Notifications. Every time new data inserted into DB on your server, server sends push notification to the client. Android client will show it as [Notification](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html).